# cookie in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement my own chrome extension which allow a user to log into a system without clicking on the extension icon.

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "form",
"description": "form",
"version": "1.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://www.example.com/*",
            "http://www.example.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js", "js/modal.js"
        ]
    }
],

"permissions": [
    "storage", "tabs", "cookies", "*://www.example.com/*"
 ],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
}
}
```

popup.js:

```
 wrapperDiv = document.createElement("div");
  wrapperDiv.setAttribute("id", "wrapper");
  wrapperDiv.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160); opacity: 0.5; z-index: 2000; height: 100%; width: 100%;");

  iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframeElement.setAttribute("style","width: 100%; height: 100%;");

  wrapperDiv.appendChild(iframeElement);

  modalDialogParentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  modalDialogParentDiv.setAttribute("id", "authModal");
  modalDialogParentDiv.setAttribute("style","position: fixed; width: 500px; border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 2001; overflow: auto; text-align: center; top: 149px; left: 497px;");

  modalDialogSiblingDiv = document.createElement("div");

  modalDialogTextDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  modalDialogTextDiv.setAttribute("style" , "text-align:center");

  modalDialogTextSpan = document.createElement("h2"); 
  modalDialogTextSpan.setAttribute("style","margin-bottom:50px; margin-top:0px; font-size: 20px !important; font-weight: 700; background-color: #435f71;color: #fff; padding: 10px 20px;"); 
  modalDialogText = document.createElement("strong");
  modalDialogText.innerHTML = "Formulaire de Connexion";
  labelErreur=document.createElement("p");
  labelErreur.setAttribute("id", "erreur");
  labelErreur.setAttribute("style", "color:red; margin-bottom:10px;");
  labelLogin=document.createElement("label");
  breakElement1 = document.createElement("br"); 
  labelLogin.innerHTML="Nom d'utilisateur: ";
  loginElement = document.createElement("input"); 
  loginElement.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 5px;");
  loginElement.setAttribute("id", "login");
  loginElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
  loginElement.setAttribute("name", "login");
  loginElement.setAttribute("required", "");

  breakElement2 = document.createElement("br"); 
  labelMdp=document.createElement("label");
  breakElement3 = document.createElement("br");
  labelMdp.innerHTML="Mot de passe: ";
  mdpElement = document.createElement("input"); 
  mdpElement.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 5px;");
  mdpElement.setAttribute("id", "mdp");
  mdpElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
  mdpElement.setAttribute("name", "mdp");
  mdpElement.setAttribute("required", "");

  breakElement4 = document.createElement("br"); 
  submitElement = document.createElement("button"); 
  submitElement.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 5px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:50px;");
  submitElement.setAttribute("id", "valid");
  submitElement.setAttribute("type", "submit");
  submitElement.setAttribute("name", "valid");
  submitElement.innerHTML="Valider";



  modalDialogTextSpan.appendChild(modalDialogText);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(modalDialogTextSpan);

  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(labelErreur);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(labelLogin);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement1);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(loginElement);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement2);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(labelMdp);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement3);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(mdpElement);
  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement4);

  modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(submitElement);


  modalDialogSiblingDiv.appendChild(modalDialogTextDiv);
  modalDialogParentDiv.appendChild(modalDialogSiblingDiv);

  $("body").append(wrapperDiv);
  $("body").append(modalDialogParentDiv);
```

when clicking on submit button i send data with ajax to have response(user_id)
which i want to remember (remember me in authentification forms)for that i have sent this user_id to background.js to set it in a cookie:

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {


   chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": "identifiant",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/*",
    "value": request
   }, function (cookie) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
     console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
     console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
   });

});

chrome.cookies.get({"url": "https://www.example.com/*", "name": "identifiant"}, function(cookie) {
    if (cookie && cookie.value!=null) {
        ID = cookie.value;


    }

});
```

Now i need to get back this cookie on popup.js to check if the user is logging in before displaying the modal